# Extension of Hoeffding-Azuma inequality

Tags: probability, martingales, machine-learning, concentration-of-measure

I'm trying to solve Exercise 20.7 in *Bandit Algorithms* by Tor Lattimore and Csaba Szepesv´ari, where it states that if the condition for the original Hoeffding-Azuma inequality is met on an event $A$, i.e.
$$
\mathbb{P}\left(\text { exists } t \in[n]: A \text { and } X_t \notin\left[a_t, b_t\right]\right)=0,
$$
then for any $\varepsilon>0,$
$$
\mathbb{P}\left(A \cap \sum_{t=1}^n\left(X_t-\mathbb{E}\left[X_t \mid \mathcal{F}_{t-1}\right]\right) \geq \varepsilon\right) \leq \exp \left(-\frac{2 n^2 \varepsilon^2}{\sum_{t=1}^n\left(b_t-a_t\right)^2}\right).
$$
I've tried to bound the mgf but falied because the event $A$ breaks the martingale structure and I just don't know how to handle it. I've also read the reference, *In Probabilistic methods for algorithmic discrete
mathematics, pages 195–248*, by C. McDiarmid, where a special event is considered, but I still can't see how to prove it in the general case.

Comment: This follows directly from Thm. 3.7 in McDiarmid's paper. Notice that the condition means that (upto a $P$-null event), $A \subset \{ \forall t, X_t \in [a_t, b_t]\}$. The latter event can serve as $B^c$ in MacDiarmid's notation. I'd suggest a more careful reading of section 3.2 of the same paper.

Comment: BTW what McDiarmid is getting into in this section is what is typically called "self-normalised concentration bounds". This paper forms a fairly accessible recent treatment of the subject https://doi.org/10.1214/18-PS321 (with further extensions to uniformity over $n$).

Comment: I think in the case you discuss here, the event $A$ has to be a subset of $\{\forall t , X_t \in [0,1]\}$. This is already exponentially unlikely, so the probability of interest is at most $2^{-n}$ no matter $\varepsilon$. I've added an argument below, let me know if it makes sense.

Comment: I just can't understand how on the event $A$ here $R^2$, in MacDiarmid's notation, can be bounded as the proof of theorem 3.14 in his paper. Like consider the case where $X_i$ are mutually independent and then the conditional range $r_i$ of $X_i$ in $\mathcal{F}_{i-1}$ should be fixed, which means $R^2$ don't have any randomness.

Comment: Let r.v. X take value in $[0,1]$ with prob 0.5 and be $k$ with prob 0.5, then it's clear that $\mathbb{P}\left(0\leq X\leq1 \cap| X-\mathbb{E}\left[X \right]|\geq \varepsilon\right) =0.5$ when $k$ is large enough for any positive $\varepsilon$, which seems to contradict with the result above(the single r.v. case, i.e. $n=1$) when pushing $\varepsilon$ to infinity.

Comment: I'm sorry that there were some typos in my replies before so I delete and reedit them.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a_t \le b_t$ be fixed numbers. Define $$ \mathcal{E}_t := \{X_t \in [a_t,b_t]\}\\ \mathcal{E}_{\le t}:= \{\forall s \le t, X_t \in  [a_t,b_t]\} = \bigcap_{s \le t} \mathcal{E}_{s} \\ \mathcal{E} := \{\forall t, X_t \in [a_t,b_t]\}.$$ Finally let $\mu_t := \mathbb{E}[X_t|\mathscr{F}_{t-1}],$ and $S_t := \sum_{s \le t} X_s - \mu_s$.

Now for any $\lambda, \varepsilon > 0,$ \begin{align} P(\mathcal{E} \cap \{S_n > \varepsilon\}) &= P(\mathcal{E} \cap \{e^{-\lambda \varepsilon + \lambda S_n } \ge 1 \}) \\
&= P(\mathbf{1}_{\mathcal{E}} \cdot e^{-\lambda\varepsilon +\lambda S_n } \ge 1) \\ &\le e^{-\lambda \varepsilon} \mathbb{E}[ \mathbf{1}_\mathcal{E} e^{\lambda S_n}].\end{align}

Now conditioning on $\mathscr{F}_{n-1}$ like in Azuma's inequality, notice that $$ \mathbb{E}[\mathbf{1}_{\mathcal{E}} e^{\lambda S_n}|\mathscr{F}_{n-1}] = \mathbf{1}_{\mathcal{E}_{\le n-1}} e^{\lambda S_{n-1}}\mathbb{E}[ \mathbf{1}_{\mathcal{E}_n}e^{\lambda (S_n - S_{n-1})} |\mathscr{F}_{n-1}].$$ Further, on ${\mathcal{E}_n}, (S_n - S_{n-1}) = X_n - \mu_n \in [a_t-\mu_n, b_t-\mu_n],$ where notice that $\mu_n$ is $\mathscr{F}_{n-1}$-measurable. So the random variable $S_n - S_{n-1}$ has bounded range given $\mathcal{E}_n$ and $\mathscr{F}_{n-1}$, and we can hit this with Hoeffding's lemma to conclude that $$ \mathbb{E}[\mathbf{1}_{\mathcal{E}_n} e^{\lambda (S_n - S_{n-1})} |\mathscr{F}_{n-1}] = \mathbf{E}[ e^{\lambda (S_n - S_{n-1})} | \mathscr{F}_{n-1}, \mathcal{E}_n] P(\mathcal{E}_n|\mathscr{F}_{n-1}) \le e^{\lambda^2 (b_n - a_n)^2/8}.$$

But now we're in business - iterate this argument to conclude tha the MGF is bounded by $e^{\lambda^2 \sum (b_t - a_t)^2/8}$ and conclude as usual. Finally notice that for any event $A$, $ A \cap \mathcal{E}_{\le n } \subset \mathcal{E}_{\le n},$ and so the same result has to hold for $P( A \cap \mathcal{E}_{\le n} \cap \{S_n \ge \varepsilon\}).$

Comment: I'm not quite sure about the meaning of $\mathbf{E}\left[\cdot \mid \mathscr{F}_{n-1}, \mathcal{E}_n\right]$ and I'm afraid that taking conditional expectation on a larger $\sigma-$field may not keep the expecation still $0$, i.e. $\mathbf{E}\left[S_n-S_{n-1} \mid \mathscr{F}_{n-1}, \mathcal{E}_n\right]=0$, which may be necessary in Hoeffding's lemma.

Comment: Considering the independent case may help see this, like consider i.i.d. r.v. $X_i$ to be 1 w.p.0.5 and -k  w.p.0.5 , then $\mathbb{E}\left[\mathbf{1}_{\mathcal{E}_n} e^{\lambda\left(S_n-S_{n-1}\right)} \mid \mathscr{F}_{n-1}\right]=\mathbb{E}\left[\mathbf{1}_{0\leq X\leq 1}e^{\lambda(X_n-\mathbb{E}[X_n])}   \right]=e^{\lambda(k+1)/2}/2$, which can not be bounded by $e^{\lambda^2/8}$ when $k$ is large.

Comment: @psms Both solid points. I'll have to have a proper think, but the example you give is very clear. Did you look through McDiarmid's proof? Is there a similar sticking point there?

Comment: First using induction he proves $\mathbf{E}\left(\boldsymbol{1}_{A} e^{h \sum Y_k} \mid \mathcal{F}_0\right) \leq \sup \left(\boldsymbol{1}_{A} \prod \mathbf{E}\left(e^{h Y_k} \mid \mathcal{F}_{k-1}\right) \mid \mathcal{F}_0\right)$, which decouples the martingale from the event. Then to bound $\boldsymbol{1}_{A}\mathbf{E}\left(e^{h Y_k} \mid \mathcal{F}_{k-1}\right)$, he just consider the special event $A$, where the conditional range $r_i$ of $Y_i$ in $\mathcal{F}_{i-1}$ is bounded.

Comment: However, as I mentioned before, when $X_i$ are mutually independent,  the conditional range $r_i$ of $X_i$ in $\mathcal{F}_{i-1}$ should be fixed, which means that such event is now just an empty set because it's about some constants.